# Split strings from nested list by delimiter

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to go from a pandas dataframe series of which the elements are strings with the following format:

```
'x ± a'
'y ± b'
'z ± c'
```

I'd like to extract the numbers x,y,z from this series into a numpy array:

```
X = np.array([x,y,z])
```

How can I do this?

I tried to turn the series into a nested list, but then I am stuck on how to apply the `.split('±')[0]` method to this nested list.

Comment: If the input were a list of strings `s`  you would do `X = np.array([v.split('±')[0] for v in s])`, but it is not, so I'm not sure if the same would work here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
a = pd.to_numeric(df['col'].str.split('±').str[0], errors='coerce').to_numpy()
```

Or (more efficient):

```
a = pd.to_numeric(df['col'].str.extract('(.*)\s*±', expand=False), errors='coerce').to_numpy()
```

Example output:

```
array([10. , 20. , 33.3])
```

Used input:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col': ['10 ± 1', '20 ± 2', '33.3 ± 3']})
```